# Symbol.Type unrecognized in Antlr4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I'm currently learning Antlr4.
There is an example in the Doc that I tried to run:

```
DefPhase.java.

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeProperty;

public class DefPhase extends CymbolBaseListener {
    ParseTreeProperty<Scope> scopes = new ParseTreeProperty<Scope>();
    GlobalScope globals;
    Scope currentScope; // define symbols in this scope
    public void enterFile(CymbolParser.FileContext ctx) {
        globals = new GlobalScope(null);
        currentScope = globals;
    }
    
    public void exitFile(CymbolParser.FileContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(globals);
    }

    public void enterFunctionDecl(CymbolParser.FunctionDeclContext ctx) {
        String name = ctx.ID().getText();
        int typeTokenType = ctx.type().start.getType();
        Symbol.Type type = CheckSymbols.getType(typeTokenType);
        
        // push new scope by making new one that points to enclosing scope
        FunctionSymbol function = new FunctionSymbol(name, type, currentScope);
        currentScope.define(function); // Define function in current scope
        saveScope(ctx, function);      // Push: set function's parent to current
        currentScope = function;       // Current scope is now function scope
    }

    void saveScope(ParserRuleContext ctx, Scope s) { scopes.put(ctx, s); }

    public void exitFunctionDecl(CymbolParser.FunctionDeclContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(currentScope);
        currentScope = currentScope.getEnclosingScope(); // pop scope
    }

    public void enterBlock(CymbolParser.BlockContext ctx) {
        // push new local scope
        currentScope = new LocalScope(currentScope);
        saveScope(ctx, currentScope);
    }

    public void exitBlock(CymbolParser.BlockContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(currentScope);
        currentScope = currentScope.getEnclosingScope(); // pop scope
    }

    public void exitFormalParameter(CymbolParser.FormalParameterContext ctx) {
        defineVar(ctx.type(), ctx.ID().getSymbol());
    }

    public void exitVarDecl(CymbolParser.VarDeclContext ctx) {
        defineVar(ctx.type(), ctx.ID().getSymbol());
    }

    void defineVar(CymbolParser.TypeContext typeCtx, Token nameToken) {
        int typeTokenType = typeCtx.start.getType();
        Symbol.Type type = CheckSymbols.getType(typeTokenType);
        VariableSymbol var = new VariableSymbol(nameToken.getText(), type);
        currentScope.define(var); // Define symbol in current scope
    }
}
```

For some reason Symbol.Type is unrecognized. After digging up it seems that the previous Antlr had a library called symtab. Latest one is 1.0.8. This library contained all the relevant definitions but still didn't contain Symbol.Type.
Does Anltr4 has a dedicated symtab?

I really need some help regarding this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example you are talking about is this here: https://github.com/remenska/Grammars/blob/master/book-examples/listeners/DefPhase.java

If you look at the package in which this lies you'll find the type Symbol (https://github.com/remenska/Grammars/blob/master/book-examples/listeners/Symbol.java) and it has the field type. Maybe you can somehow use this. So it really comes from just from this book examples it seems.

Comment: Hi. 
You were right. It seems that the symtab library is a newer version an contains more files that probably handle more cases. I must admit that it's a bit odd, because the examples in Antlr4 are 8 years old, and the symtab is about 3-4 years old..
I'm pasting the link to symtab. I'm pretty sure it can be adjusted to work with Antlr4's examples (latest is 1.0.8):
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.antlr/symtab/1.0.8/source-code